# How can i get the first column from group by ? Python Panda

Tags: python, arrays, pandas-groupby

Here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[0,0,1,14,15,30,31,50,51,79,78,45,22,15,80]})
print(df['Age']) 
a=df.groupby(['Age']).size()

print(a)
```

Output:

```
Age
0     2
1     1
14    1
15    2
22    1
30    1
31    1
45    1
50    1
51    1
78    1
79    1
80    1
dtype: int64
```

I want to get age as a first column and size as a second column into an array.
How can i do that?

Comment: Use `df.groupby('Age').size().reset_index(name='count')`

Comment: @jezrael it worked! thank you